# Why do I get \N when executing INTO OUTFILE query?

Tags: java, mysql

I am connecting to a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database using Java. I am executing this query:

```
    String query = 
        "SELECT * FROM TT2 " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "`Language Pref` " + 
        "ON tt2.msisdn =  `language pref`.MDN " +
            "INTO OUTFILE 'c:/test12226.csv' " + 
            "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  " +
            "ENCLOSED BY '\"'  " +
            "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

I am executing this query using executeQuery(query).

The [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file generated is perfect except for the last column. In the original table called `Language Pref` the last column had some null or empty cells. In the CSV file, wherever there were these null cells in the original table language pref, I am getting "\N" instead of the null cells as should be.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `,\n` at the end of a line represents a null-value in the last column. So everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a '\' char in a String, you need to type '\\'.

Example:

```
System.out.print("The newline char \\n makes a new line: \n");
```

So in your example your last line should read:

```
"LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";
```

Answer (score 1):

The string \N is used to represent a null value. So it's the right answer.

\n is completely different, that is a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:
`ifnull(fieldname, '')` to avoid this.

This will put `''` instead of NULL thus you'll get empty strings in your output file. The only problem is that you'll have to specify it individually for every columns.

NOTE: The '\N' seems to appear only when opened with Excel.